# Object property instance on class?

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, rdfs, protege4

Let's say for example:

```
-Food(class
 -Bread(instance of Food!
-Species(class
  -Animal(class
    - Horse(class
      -Unicorn(instance
```

Now I need to be able to set Bread -> eatableBy -> Horse. But I can't make a object property assertion to a class. So I could set it eatable by and add all the instances of Horse, but I have a lot of instances so that would be a bit redundant. Does anybody know a good efficient way to do achieve the same effect?

E.g. If I need to know what Horses can eat it needs to return Bread also. If I want to know all the food an Unicorn can eat, it needs to return Bread (because it's a horse and all horses eat bread).  If I need to know what the subclasses of Animal eat, it also has to return Bread.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you don't want bread to be a class?

Comment: Well it's a specific type of food, and has data properties and object properties, which a class can't have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have an *instance* **Bread** and want to ensure that it is eatable by every instance of the *class* **Horse**.  OWL has *value restrictions* which let you describe the set of individuals that stand in some relation to some particular value.  E.g., the expression

likes **value** Pizza

is the class of all individuals that like pizza.  OWL also lets you use the inverse of properties, so that the expression

**inverse**(likes) **value** Joe

is the class of all things that Joe likes.  These class expressions can be used in axioms, including subclass axioms.  In particular, you could say that

Horse **SubClassOf** canEat **value** Bread

to say that every individual of type **Horse** can eat the individual **Bread**.  Rather than a canEat property, though, you've got an eatableBy property.  That's just the inverse of canEat, though, so you can say that every individual of type **Horse** can eat the individual **Bread** with the axiom:

Horse **SubClassOf** **inverse**(eatableBy) **value** Bread

In Protégé, that looks like:

[image: protege screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I set the subclass inverse rule but when querying uni:Horse canEat ?y gives no results. Also querying uni:Bread uni:eatableBy ?y gives no result. Tried it with SPARQL and Snap SPARQL

Comment: @vincentkleine The axiom "Horse SubClassOf (eatableBy value Bread)" *does* say that Bread is eatableBy every instance of Horse, and a reasoner will be able to confirm that.  So, a couple of questions: 1. Do you have any instances of Horse declared?  2.  Do you have a reasoner enabled?  3.  Does the SPARQL engine you're using include the results from reasoners?

Comment: I was trying to query uni:Horse(class) uni:canEat ?y, I now see when I query uni:Unicorn(instance of horse) uni:canEat ?y does gives the right result. To determine what a Horse or Animal(superclass of Horse) can eat I just need to query what the instances of Horse, or the instances of the subclasses from Animal can eat. So thank you it works now!

Comment: I would add the fact that eatableBy is likely not symmetric - I don't think bread is going to eat unicorns - is `Bread -> eatableBy(symmetric) -> Horse` a typo?