# OWL how to force all the instances of a specific class to have a specific relationship

Tags: semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

I am building an Ontology.

I have a *Class* called `Vehicle`

I have an *Object Property* called `hasType`

I have a *Class* called `VehicleTypes`

How can I force all the instances from `Vehicle` class to have **one and just one** instance of `VehicleTypes`

#### What I have tried

I am working on Protege.

1. I made the `hasType` as a functional property.
2. I added an `Equivalent To` which is like this: hasType exactly 1 VehicleTypes

Is that enough please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Object property instance on class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29276563/object-property-instance-on-class)

Answer (score 0):

Making `hasType` functional is the right move since every `Vehicle` can only have one `VehicleType`. However, you need to describe `Vehicle hasType exactly 1 VehicleType` as a `subClassOf` relation rather than `equivalentTo` relation.

Definition of subclass relation:

> if the class description C1 is defined as a subclass of class description C2, then the set of individuals in the class extension of C1 should be a subset of the set of individuals in the class extension of C2.

Definition of equivalent relation:

> links a class description to another class description. The meaning of such a class axiom is that the two class descriptions involved have the same class extension (i.e., both class extensions contain exactly the same set of individuals).

Comment: In a clearer way, if you use `equivalent To` relation between `Vehicle` and `hasType exactly 1 VehicleType`, then any instance which has exactly one `VehicleType` as a property is an instance of `Vehicle`.

Answer (score 0):

The following axiom is sufficient to guarantee that all the instances from the `Vehicle` class have one and just one instance of `VehicleTypes` (in Manchester syntax):

```
Class: Vehicle
    SubClassOf: hasType exactly 1 VehicleType
```

This, in fact, is the minimal ontology that guarantees it. If you do not need to be minimal, you can also enforce it with the following:

```
ObjectProperty: hasType
    Characteristics: Functional
Class: Vehicle
    SubClassOf: hasType some VehicleType
```

This can be useful if you use a reasoner that does not support cardinality restrictions, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create your own vehicleType property and VehicleType class, just use `rdf:Type` and `rdfs:subClassOf`:

```
:Car rdfs:subClassOf  :Vehicle.
:Boat rdfs:subClassOf :Vehicle.
```

Then if you want to say that certain classes are disjunctive, use:

```
:Car owl:disjointWith :Boat.
```